# How to write ages and dates in a newspaper article inside a work of fiction

Tags: fiction

I'm trying to write a newspaper article inside my work of fiction. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to write ages and dates in this article.

I took journalism in college, and I know that if I am submitting an article to a newspaper, I would need to write ages and dates as numbers: July 22, 2016, Nathan Smith, 34. But if I am putting this in a work of fiction, do I do it like this, or do I write the ages and dates as words?

For example:

John Smith, 37, was arrested on July 10, 2016, or

John Smith,, thirty-seven was arrested on July tenth, twenty-sixteen.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

If you're "reproducing" a newspaper article in your book, write it exactly as you would an actual newspaper article. That makes it look real, and helps keep the suspension of disbelief for your reader.

Answer (score 3):

**There is actually quite a variety in the way dates are depicted in a newspaper article.**

It depends, as usual, on the nature of the event. Please note that the samples below are all fairly old. A quick scan of today's newspapers and on-line publications seems to show that detailed dates are on the decline, with just plain weekdays mentioned most frequent for subjects that happened at a specific moment.

**Some samples:**

**'Thursday night' for a well-known headline event.**

[image]

**'April 6' for a snippet about an obscure discovery.**

[image]

**'Friday, Dec. 9' for a courtroom report.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Definitely numbers, not words, in this case.  The second way you have it written does not track at all with a newspaper article. It looks more like some kind of scientific paper.

Answer (score 1):

With each number written out in letters, readers will, more likely than not, skip over that part because it's slightly tedious to read.

If the date and\or age in question is of any importance--be it minor or crucial-- to the plot, use quick and simple numbers.
And good luck with your writing!